# How to insert only in join table but not in reference table in JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities `User` and `Role`. A user can have multiple roles and each role can be associated with multiple users. i.e., User-Role have many-many relationship

eg: users *Ram*, *Rob*, and *John* are admins

I am creating a join table between User and Role to store the information.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Transient
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Column
    private boolean deleted;

}
```

And Role.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
@Data
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="role_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="role",unique=true)
    private String role;

}
```

When this is executed in spring boot, the following tables are being created: `account`, `user_role`, `role`.

Since my number of roles are fixed. I inserted them manually

```
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (1,'ADMIN');
INSERT INTO `role` VALUES (2,'USER');
```

Now from my java spring boot application, I try to insert a new entry in account table. An attempt is done to insert a new entry in `Role` table as well... I want to insert this only in `account` and `user_role` tables but not in `role` table...

Can anyone let me know how to do it?

UPDATE:

here is account insertion part(create account piece of code)

//Create account

```
public Account createAccount(AccountDto account) {

        Account newAccount = new Account();
        newAccount.setPassword(account.getPassword());
        newAccount.setUsername(account.getUsername());
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setRole(account.getRole());
        roles.add(role);
        newAccount.setRoles(roles);
        Account savedAccount = save(newAccount);
        return savedAccount;
    }
```

//Update Account

```
public Account updateAccount(String oldUserName, AccountDto accountDto) {
        Account account = accountRepository.findByUsername(oldUserName);
        if (account != null) {
            Set<Role> roleset = new HashSet<Role>();
            if(accountDto.getRole() != null && !accountDto.getRole().isEmpty()){
                Role role = roleRepository.findByRole(accountDto.getRole());
                if (role == null) {
                    roleset.add(role);
                }
            }
            account.setRoles(roleset);
            account.setUsername(accountDto.getUsername());
            account = accountRepository.save(account);
            return account;
        } else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your 'insert a new entry in account table` code could be useful. I think you are trying to insert a new user by setting his role to `new Role()` instead of getting the role from db first.

Comment: _" I try to insert a new entry in account table"_... How? Do you have any code that can share with us?

Comment: added @KamilNoster  with insertion and updation piece of code

Comment: @lealceldeiro  added code

Comment: @stallion I'm not sure about how are you trying to update the account. What's the role of `accountDto` here? is it supposed to bring the roles that must be set to `account` or it is just a data access object which fetch from database, some sort of repository?

Comment: accountDto is supposed to interact with UI to get only some information.. i dont want them to set "set of roles" but only set one value for role.. Also i dont want to set deleted field of account.. so accountDto is subset of Account.. i think that doesnt matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to complite CascadeType in Account class.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.)
```

You need to add link for the Account Entity as well.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.MERGE
        },
        mappedBy = "role")
private Set<Account> accounts = new Set<Account>();
```

You can find nice tutorial in here https://www.callicoder.com/hibernate-spring-boot-jpa-many-to-many-mapping-example/

Comment: I am getting this exception:  Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.techjava.springbootsecuritymysql.model.Role